# jQuery selector, search multiple words

Tags: jquery

I have a selector like this

```
var word = 'word';
$('#id tr:not(.class):has(*>a[href*="'+word+'"])').css('color','red')
```

This only works for one word.

How can I make it search multiple words (more than 10)?

Comment: can you continue with new statement :has()? :has(word1):has(word2)

Comment: or you might loop it with FOR iterator

Comment: looks like you need to use `filter` instead of stuffing everything into a query string.

Comment: @Armand it will be long line.

Comment: @KingKing i've tried using filter, but i don't know how to make it works :(

Comment: @AMZMA then loop is your friend. Your question states - how to do it? but not how to make it short. I think you've got a couple of correct answers here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd select multiple elements within `has()` using a comma:

```
$('#id tr:not(.class):has(*>a[href*="word"], *>a[href*="another"])').css('color','red')
```

You could create an array of words and map them to a selector-like string and put that in there instead, to make your selector a little nicer:

```
var varr = ['makan','another','final'],
    aQuery = $.map(varr, function(el){ return '*>a[href*="'+el+'"]'; }).join(",");

$('#id tr:not(.class):has('+aQuery+')').css('color','red')
```

Comment: thaaaanksss, this is what I want :D

Answer (score 0):

You can include as many selectors as you want by separating them with a comma. For example, if you need to select both paragraphs with a class `hello` and lists with class `world`, you can do:

```
$('p.hello, ul.world, ol.world')
```

For the sake of readability, I would rather have an array of words, loop through them and add the colors for each word.

---

Note: in your case, wouldn't it be simpler to distinguish the links on server-side, put a class on the links you want to match, and then use a class-based selector instead of attribute selectors?

Comment: can't make on server-side, this is for userscript
thanks anyway :D